# Horizontally scroll table cells if they are too long to fit in a 100% width table without scaling

Tags: html-table

I have a table with 3 columns.

The width of the cable is `100%`, so it fills the full viewport with the cells as wide as they need to be.

However, if I have a really long cell that makes the table too wide to fit in `100%`, the entire table scales down until eventually the text is too small to read.

Instead, I want the long cell to begin scrolling with `overflow-x: scroll`. I cannot get this working.

My code:

```
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px; solid;
    border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
td.long-cell {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Short String</td>
        <td>Short String</td>
        <td class="long-cell">Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong String</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1evn9cm/)

If you make the viewport smaller with dev tools, the table starts shrinking.

I've tried using `table-layout: fixed`, however this then means that I have to set fixed widths on the columns, which I can't do as the content is of unpredictable lengths.

Essentially I want a table that is **always** `100%` wide, **never** scales, and the cells can be scrolled horizontally **only if needed**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting `max-width: 40vw` on the cells that might get too long.

You can try different vw values, however anything between 1 and 99 seems to work somewhat.